# What does '-' mean in matlab code

Tags: matlab

Can some one explain what this line here does? This is part of an old matlab code I need to reuse for my work

```
matdir = [params.ariens '-' num2str(dirtimes(ii))];
```

I'm especially confused about the `'-'` part. Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: this is just string concatenation

Answer (score 4):

Single quotes are used to create a string literal so `'-'` simply creates a string containing the hyphen character. In MATLAB, `[ ... ]` [performs horizontal concatenation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/redefining-concatenation-for-your-class.html) so the line that you have shown concatenates the string stored in `params.ariens`, the character `'-'` and the number `dirtimes(ii)` converted to a string using `num2str` to creat one long string made up of those three strings.

For example:

```
c = ['abc', '-', 'def']
%   abc-def

class(c)
%   char

d = ['abc', '-', num2str(10)]
%   abc-10
```